# Get caret positon in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a `contenteditable div`, I have some text and an image like
`He✈llo`.

But in the js file the `contenteditable div` is like `He<img src="plane.gif">llo`
When I put cursor after the airplane and use window.getSelection.getRangeAt(0) then it shows cursor/caret position as 3. What I need is that it shows caret position as 24 i.e reading image as an img tag and shows the position of caret at the end of the img tag.

Is there any way to achieve this??

I made this http://plnkr.co/edit/Qlhzxsqko3coXe9iWl0r?p=preview Its not working correctly but it will give you an idea of what I am trying to say

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well what do you want to do, then this should resolve your problem(just click between different chars from text):

```js
$('p').bind('click', function(event) {
  finalCount = 0;
  var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var count = 0;
  $($(this).contents()).each(function(index, val) {

    if ($(val).html() == null) {
      count += selection.startOffset;
    } else {
      count += $(val).get(0).outerHTML.length;
    }
    if ($(val).text() == selection.startContainer.nodeValue) {
      console.log('found!');
      finalCount = count;
    }
  });

  alert(finalCount);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p class="text" style="margin-left:5px">He
    <img src="http://www.micronas.com/sites/all/themes/micronas/images/icons/image-x-generic.png">llo</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. It works well but I was coding in angular, so maybe I'll wait if someone can help me using angular things. Else I'll accept your answer.